# how to make celery able to handle custom import

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

hello every one how do i make celery able to handle custom models, i have a model i want to perform some tasks on i tried importing it but i keeps throwing errors, below is the code.
the error tend to be based on the registered apps, please how can i resolve the issue? i have my celery instance defined in my asgi.py all is set including redis setup

CELERY.PY

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from ecoperative.tasks import savings_increment
from django.conf import settings

from .load_env import load_env

load_env()

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "agric360.settings")


app = Celery("agric360")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.conf.beat_schedule={
    'increment':{
        'task':savings_increment(),
        'schedule':crontab(minute=1)

    }
}


app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

TASKS.PY

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from app.models import User
from wallet.models import Wallet
import datetime
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger


# logger=get_task_logger(__name__)


# # @shared_task
# # def print_hello():
# #     print('hello')

@shared_task
def savings_increment():
    # print('hello')
    wallets=Wallet.objects.all()
    

    for wallet in wallets:
        date_range=datetime.datetime.now().second-wallet.savings_timestamp.second
        if wallet.savings  != 0:
            if wallet.savings_timestamp is not None:
                if date_range >= 30:
                    wallet.savings+=2
                    wallet.save()
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
```

The error encountered is indicated below

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 386, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\_init.py", line 92, in __getattr_
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\_init_.py", line 79, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\_init.py", line 190, in __init_
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\agric360\_init_.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\agric360\celery.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ecoperative.tasks import savings_increment
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\ecoperative\tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.models import User
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\backend-main\app\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import (
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 127, in _new_
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config     
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\django\backend-main\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 138, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```